# "npm postinstall" not running in docker

Tags: docker

I have an angular app which requires following steps:

1. npm install
2. npm postinstall
3. npm run

I have automated steps via dockerfile, all above three steps run fine manullay, but when dockerfile is run, it gives error of missing "npm postinstall" script:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run postinstall' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

what might be the issue?

Answer (score 7):

Npm may refuse to run postinstall script with root account
You will have to use non privileged user in docker or simply run `npm i --unsafe-perm`